# Learning Haskell: String manipulation question

Tags: string, haskell

How can I write a function in Haskell, that takes an input string in the format a1a2a3 and expands into a1a2a2a3a3a3. For example input string "code" would be expanded into "coodddeeee"

Comment: Please post the code  you have written to solve this so far. Otherwise people may suspect this is homework.

Comment: I assure you, this is not homework :) I was working thru the excersises in a Haskell book and my brain just freezed up over this. All I know at this point is, that I will need to use ++ operator, some kind of array manipulation and possible use the length function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably very inefficient :)

```
f :: Int -> [Char] -> [Char]
f _ [] = []
f n (c:s) = (replicate n c) ++ (f (n+1) s)

g :: [Char] -> [Char]
g s = f 1 s
```

.

```
*Main> g "code"
"coodddeeee"
```

Comment: FYI: juxtaposition binds more tightly than anything but @, so you can remove a few overly paranoid parentheses. f n (c:s) = replicate n c ++ f (n+1) s

Answer (score 19):

So you want the `nth` character repeated `n` times.

```
f :: String -> String
f x = concatMap g  (zip x [1..])
   where
       g (x,y) = replicate y x
```

I'm sure there's an easier way to do this.

Explanation: First we get the string and pair it with it's place in the list (starting at 1). This is what zip does:

```
Prelude> zip "code" [1..]
[('c',1),('o',2),('d',3),('e',4)]
```

Now the function `g (x,y)` uses the replicate function which replicates whatever you want y times. So we replicate x, y times.

```
Prelude> g ('z',4)
"zzzz"
```

If we map this function over the list produced you get the result:

```
Prelude> map g $ zip "code" [1..]
["c","oo","ddd","eeee"]
```

If you have a list of strings, you can concatenate them together using `concat`. `concatMap` applies the function `g` to each pair of letter and number and then concatenates the string into the final result.

```
Prelude> concat $ map g $ zip "code" [1..]
"coodddeeee"
```

Basically: `concat $ map g` -> `concatMap g`

EDIT: now it works, it can also be done in one line thusly:

```
f x = concatMap (\(a,b)->replicate b a ) $ zip x [1..]
```

Output:

```
Prelude> f "lambda"
"laammmbbbbdddddaaaaaa"
```

Comment: Jonno... Could you explain that answer, As someone who is in the very early stages of learning haskell, the above answer just does not make sense to me.

Comment: I'd replace `g` with `uncurry . flip replicate`. Does the same thing, but uses standard Haskell library functions.

Comment: I don't think this person would understand currying at this point in learning Haskell.

Comment: Jonno... Thanks for the detailed explanation,However I chose another answer, because the simplicity of that answer appealed to me

Comment: Short version: `f = concat . zipWith replicate [1..]`

Comment: Or if you (*cough*) happen to have a string of length > maxBound::Int, then you could use genericReplicate...

Comment: sdcvvc should post his comment as an answer -- it is really the clearest way to me.

Comment: trinithis: If you have a string of length == maxBound::Int on a 32-bit machine, the result of applying this function to that string will be 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 2147483647 = 2305843 terabytes - assuming 1 byte per character and ignoring the list overhead.  Luckily Haskell is lazy so you probably won't need to allocate it all at once, although you'll still be waiting a long time just to walk to the end :-)

Answer (score 15):

```
import Control.Monad
f = zip [1..] >=> uncurry replicate
```

yields

```
Main> f "code"
"coodddeeee"
```

Comment: Nice! For those people like me, who don't know the type of the operator: "Left-to-right Kleisli composition of monads: `(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> (a -> m c)`"

Answer (score 4):

Why do people hate list comprehensions?

```
Prelude> let f s = concat [ replicate x y | (x,y) <- zip [1..] s]
Prelude> f "code"
"coodddeeee"
```

or if you want to go crazy with extensions

```
Prelude> :set -XParallelListComp
Prelude> let f s = concat [ replicate x y | x <- [1..] | y <- s]
Prelude> f "code"
"coodddeeee"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Prelude> let l = "code" in concat $ [take y $ repeat (last $ take y l) | y <- [1..length l]]
"coodddeeee"
```